# passing sentence as a argument in subprocess command

Tags: python, command-line

I am executing python script inside another script and want to pass two arguments to it

```
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in open('que.txt')]
for l in lines:
    print 'my sentence : '
    print l
    #os.system("find_entity.py")  //this also does not work
    subprocess.call(" python find_entity.py l 1", shell=True) //this works but l does not considered as sentence which was read
```

what is the correct approach?

update:

```
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in open('q0.txt')]
for line_num, line in enumerate(lines):
    cmd = ["python", "find_entity.py", line]
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

then it goes to python terminal

Comment: can you  not do a `import find_entity` and call the procedures from there?

Comment: @Joram: actually that was the best approach but it did not strike, I am bad at OOP. Any suggestion for better OO concept clearing in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of string substitution mechanics:

- [C-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

  in your case it would looks like

  ```
  subprocess.call("python find_entity.py %s %d" % (line, line_num))
  ```
- [C#-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)

  ```
  subprocess.call("python find_entity.py {} {}".format(line, line_num))
  ```
- or [templates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)

Or, in case with `subprocess` library you should pass arguments as list to `call` function:

```
subprocess.call(["python", "find_entity.py", line, str(line_num)])
```

Look at `line` and `line_num` variables — they pass without any quotes, so they would be passed by value.
This solution is recommended, because it provides more clean and obvious code and provide correct parameter's processing(such as whitespace escaping, etc).

However, if you want to use `shell=True` flag for `subprocess.call`, solution with list of args will not work instead of string substitution solutions. BTW, `subprocess` and `os` provides all shell powerful options: such as script piping, expanding user home directory(~), etc. So, if you will code big and complicated script you should use python libraries instead of using `shell=True`.

Comment: thanks, but when I tried third way, it takes me to python terminal. I execute like this `python script.py`

Comment: why you use `shell=True` in your script? if it is not necessary, you can change it to False and all will work fine

Comment: The two using string formatting are not recommended, as certain arguments (such as those containing whitespace) will not be quoted properly. Stick with the version that uses a list.

Answer (score 1):

you need the contents of variable l (I renamed it to line), not the string literal "l"

```
for line_num, line in enumerate(lines):
    cmd = ["python",
           "find_entity.py",
           line,
           str(line_num)]
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: thanks dear, but still getting `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
`

Comment: `subprocess.call` accepts only lists of strings, so you should convert `line_num` to string. Use string substituion or explicitly call to `str(line_num)`!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the command name and its arguments in separate variables, or already in a list, you almost never want to use `shell=True`. (It's not illegal, but its behavior is undocumented and generally not what is wanted.)

```
cmd = ["python", "find_entity.py", line]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```